# Should I show the rating breakdown for a product review

Tags: ratings, information-design, rating-system

I'm putting together a design for a course review card, but I'm unsure whether I should include a breakdown of the overall rating. When submitting a review, a user has to rate three categories, for the sake of confidentiality I named them Category One, Category Two, Category Three.

When displaying a review, I'm displaying an overall rating (an average of three categories), and also a rating breakdown (the scores of each individual category). I've decided to do this as I think the overall score alone isn't enough to make a judgment on the course. However, from a UI perspective, I'm worried it'll be cluttered.

Design 1
[image]

Design 2
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Another option: bring the rating formula together and emphasize the base score, and allow users to visually parse each category rating.

Placing the 'formula' (categories) in the same space keeps all aspects left by the reviewer in one area. The right pane is *my assessment of the review.*

#### How do your users assess the rating formula?

I know this is not part of your question, but visually, the review total score (or the average) is a little visually hidden from me.

Then I have to jump down further to see how that formula is arrived at.

**Some information design / hierarchy**

Can you keep the rating (and its formula) in close proximity?

The main Rating score is the final number, but let them visually assess the categories. This way I can immediately see *how the formula is calculated* and there may be certain categories that are important for me to base decisions on.

[image]

#### Trip advisor: review & info hierarchy

[Trip Advisor gives both an overall, and a breakdown](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g187323-d200444-Reviews-Park_Hotel_Berlin_Neukolln-Berlin.html). This at the **aggregate level** not the individual review level. However, the rating is very clear and catches the eye quickly:

[image]

For instance, location may be super important, but I don't care as much about service (I just need a room to sleep in). This shows me without having to read.